# Show that $g\circ f$ is Riemann-Integrable too.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, riemann-integration

> Let $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$  be a Riemann-Integrable function.
>
> Show that $g\circ f$ is Riemann-Integrable too.

**ATTEMPT**:

Investigating the set of points of discontinuity of $g\circ f$ we get that if $f$ is  discontinuous at $a$ then $g\circ f$ is discontinuous at $g(a)$
since

$f$ is  discontinuous at $a\implies \lim _{x\to a} f(x)\neq f(a)\implies g(\lim _{x\to a} f(x))\neq g(f(a))\implies \lim _{x\to a} g\circ f(x)\neq g(f(a))$ since $g$ is continuous.

So the set of all points of discontinuity of $g\circ f\subset $ set of all points of discontinuity of $f$.

Since set of all points of discontinuity of $f$ has measure $0$ so does the set of all points of discontinuity of $g\circ f$.
So $g\circ f$ is  Riemann-Integrable.

Is the proof correct?Please help

Comment: Since $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, the limit $\lim _{x\to a} f(x)$ might not exists.

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, then $g\circ f$ can nevertheless be continuous there. Consider e.g. the case when $g$ is constant. The other direction, a discontinuity of $g\circ f$ at $a$ implies a discontinuity of $f$ at $a$, is true, and it is what you need.

Comment: What does it mean for $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to be Riemann integrable?